# Save json information in objects in windows store app

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

In a windows store app project i get a Json with several items  from a webserver that looks like this 
http://paste2.org/dJP85EOJ (this is one item)

i then have a method that reads the json information and creates a object with that information

```
public async Task createMeet(IJsonValue item, List<Meeting> listMeetings)
    {

        Meeting meeting = new Meeting();
        List<MeetingInvitee> invitees = new List<MeetingInvitee>();
        List<MeetingPoint> meetingPoints = new List<MeetingPoint>();
        MeetingsDB MeetForDB = new MeetingsDB();
        GappService gappservice = new GappService();



        try
        {

            JsonObject newMeet;
            JsonObject.TryParse(item.Stringify(), out newMeet);

            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("_id"))
                if (newMeet["_id"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.Id = newMeet["_id"].GetString();

                    MeetForDB.Id = newMeet["_id"].GetString();
                }
            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("name"))
                if (newMeet["name"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.Name = newMeet["name"].GetString();
                    MeetForDB.Name = newMeet["name"].GetString();
                }
            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("description"))
                if (newMeet["description"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.Description = newMeet["description"].GetString();
                    MeetForDB.description = newMeet["description"].GetString();
                }
            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("meetingType"))
                if (newMeet["meetingType"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.MeetingType = newMeet["meetingType"].GetString();
                    MeetForDB.meetingType = newMeet["meetingType"].GetString();
                }
            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("meetingStatus"))
                if (newMeet["meetingStatus"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.Status = newMeet["meetingStatus"].GetString();
                    MeetForDB.meetingStatus = newMeet["meetingStatus"].GetString();
                }
            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("organizer"))
                if (newMeet["organizer"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.Organizer = newMeet["organizer"].GetString();
                    MeetForDB.organizer = newMeet["organizer"].GetString();
                }
            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("alternativeOrganizer"))
                if (newMeet["alternativeOrganizer"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.AlternativeOrganizer = newMeet["alternativeOrganizer"].GetString();
                    MeetForDB.alternativeOrganizer = newMeet["alternativeOrganizer"].GetString();
                }
            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("organization"))
                if (newMeet["organization"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.Organization = newMeet["organization"].GetString();
                    MeetForDB.organization = newMeet["organization"].GetString();
                }

            if (newMeet.ContainsKey("startDate"))
                if (newMeet["startDate"].ValueType != JsonValueType.Null)
                {
                    meeting.StartDate = GetDateTime(newMeet["startDate"].GetNumber());
                    MeetForDB.startDate = newMeet["startDate"].GetNumber();
                }

                ....
}
```

its quite a long method with some nested foreachs inside it, and because of that it takes some seconds to create the final object.

What i would like to know is if there is a way of passing the json information to a Object directly without having to read 1 field at a time.

Comment: Did you build a class that represents the response from the server?

Comment: I have several classes, a main one, and then some other smaller ones

Comment: If you have a class structure that mirrors the JSON being returned (looks like mongoose/mongodb), then I'd expect the deserialization to work.

Answer (score 1):

Typically I'd point you to something like [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) but the complexity of your JSON is more than it can handle.

Instead I'd look to have the server return less or format it in a way that is easier to consume. The intent being that a change in one place on the server can make things faster for all who are consuming it.
If you don't control the server then you could consider creating your own server that sits between the app and the one providing the content. Yes, there can be additional development/maintenance/running costs associated with this and it will be up to you to decide if they are worth it for the benefits (smaller, faster downloads; simpler processing code; better caching; faster code/app; and more...) they bring.

Comment: i was trying to use json.net but still having some problems